# Pointers and Arrays in C++(Multidimensional Pointer)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
int a[2][3];
int b[2][3];
int d[5][3];
int **q[3] = {a, b, d};
```

why is this following piece of code showing an error?

```
error:a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:12:19: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[3]’ to ‘int**’ in initialization
   12 |     int **q[3] = {a, b, d};
      |                   ^
      |                   |
      |                   int (*)[3]
a.cpp:12:22: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[3]’ to ‘int**’ in initialization
   12 |     int **q[3] = {a, b, d};
      |                      ^
      |                      |
      |                      int (*)[3]
a.cpp:12:25: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[3]’ to ‘int**’ in initialization
   12 |     int **q[3] = {a, b, d};
      |                         ^
      |                         |
      |                         int (*)[3]
```

i tried changing the parameters but nothing happens

Comment: `cannot convert ‘int (*)[3]’ to ‘int**’` What is unclear?

Comment: Exactly what all three messages say.   `a`, `b`, and `d` are all arrays of arrays.   An array of arrays cannot be implicitly converted to a pointer to a pointer.       The so-called "pointer decay" (conversion of an array to a pointer, which is equal to the address of its first element) only works in one dimension.

Comment: In such cases, use 'auto' instead of int**. Then, see what intellisense gives you, and write that down.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.  Likewise, arrays of arrays are not pointers that are pointing to pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration here:

```
int **q[3] = {a, b, d};
```

.... is declaring an array of three `pointers-to-pointer-to-int` (aka `int **`).

If `a`, `b`, and `d` were pointers-to-pointers-to-int, it would work; however, they are not that; rather they are two-dimensional arrays of integers.  Hence the type-conversion errors.

If you're wondering what the difference is, consider that a two-dimensional array is always a completely contiguous block in memory:  i.e. `int a[2][3]`'s contents are laid out like this in RAM (each row below represents one `int`, i.e. either 4 or 8 bytes or RAM):

```
a[0][0]
a[0][1]
a[0][2]
a[1][0]
a[1][1]
a[1][2]
```

... and to compute the address of `a[X][Y]`, the compiler would (internally) generate code something like this:  `int * ptr = &a[0][0] + (X*3) + Y` ... note that only one address is used (`&a[0][0]`) and then we just add the appropriate array-offset to that base-address to calculate the correct location in the two-dimensional array.

... whereas a table based on a real double-indirect pointer array might look something like this:

```
int row0[5];
int row1[8];
int row2[7];
int * q[3] = {row0, row1, row2};
int ** pq = q; // a pointer to an array-of-pointers is the same as a pointer-to-the-first-pointer-in-the-array
```

Here we've declared each row as a separate one-dimensional array, and then we construct an array of pointers, with each pointer representing one row of the table.  This has the advantage of allowing us to make each row a different length, if we want, but the disadvantage of making the memory layout less compact (e.g. row0 and row1 might be far apart from each other in RAM) and each lookup of an `int` in the table now requires two pointer-dereferences rather than one.